# SSIS Package Created and Executed via Code Requires Service to be Restarted after Multiple Runs

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

we have existing C# code to dynamically create SSIS packages that reads from different files and into a SQL Server 2016 database. It does what we need it to, but stumbled into an issue that we remain unable to resolve: being unable to keep running the .Execute command without having to restart our custom Windows service.

Right now the limit is at 2 files. If we run our code that calls the Execute command the third time, it will get stuck up on post validate based from what we're logging via the Component and Run Event handlers, and we couldn't proceed until we restart the Windows service and run again. We cannot just always restart the service because there could be other processes that can be disrupted if we go with that approach.

Things we've tried so far:

1. Extract the dtsx package that the code creates and attempt to run it using dtexec or BIDS locally. No errors / warnings raised, and we can keep re-running the same package over and over without fail.
2. Run the same code locally. Same result as #1.
3. Run a SQL trace with the help of our DBA. Confirmed that we have no queries locking the destination table and the database itself. We did observe some SPIDs being retained after the third run but all are in a sleeping state.
4. Modify our RunEventHandler and ComponentEventHandler to log which step is the process in. Also tried enabling logging via Event Viewer. No errors, really just getting stuck at post-validate as mentioned earlier come the third run.
5. Explicitly call the SSIS dispose methods, even tried explicitly disposing the connection managers themselves.
6. Play around the DelayValidations and ValidateExternalMetadata properties.

Any chance others have encountered this before and were able figure out what's causing this?

Comment: Questions about code that show no code are notoriously difficult to troubleshoot. To get my mind in the right place, your service identifies source files, creates a custom package to ingest it and then executes it. Two concurrent executions are fine, but when it picks up a third file, the package generation is good but the run hangs after the validate steps fire? Or are you saying the same file format, same package hangs on third round of running?

Comment: It's the latter. So even if I use the same exact file that adds the same number of records to the same table within the database, it will freeze up at the third attempt.

Comment: Does a cycle of processing include create package + execution or is it create package and run 3x to reproduce the issue? Anything special in the package? Just trying to fathom a repro

Comment: A cycle of processing is creating the package and then execution. Freezes up at the 3rd cycle come execution time.

Comment: And to point #2, does that mean running the same code but not as a service or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: So same core code works fine as a console app or windows form app - "some something" and it runs through 3+ cycles of create & execute package. Same code in a windows service wrapper hangs in validation after the second loop. Smells like something is awry with the windows service definition, yeah?

Comment: I ran some more debugging today and discovered that the issue doesn't persist if I run the same code through a web application hosted via IIS, so yeah, it is consistent with your latest comment. Thanks for talking me through this issue. It stands to question what could be different between the service and an web based app (they use the same user account) as it should be just running the same thing. Hopefully I learn more to why soon.

Comment: I accept the role of rubber duck ;) It could be something with an event being raised that the service is snippy about that other run containers disregard

Comment: We've figured out the difference. So when it's run using our Windows service, it does so by calling it through a separate and new AppDomain. It seems like a thread or something to that effect isn't able to finish through it. Unloading the domain after a package is run prevents the freezing, at the cost of an UnloadDomainException. What we're trying to understand now is as to why SSIS wouldn't be able to properly wrap up itself within that separate domain. I'm not sure if it's related but the domain when run through the service resides in the server's D drive vs. in C:\Windows.

Comment: Looking forward to you self-answering this as this will be one of those searches that [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/979/) writes about

Answer (score 1):

To expound on the latest comment, we've found that the issue stems from the fact that we're calling a separate AppDomain to take care of running the job and consequently executing the package. The way this separate AppDomain is created is via CreateInstanceAndUnwrap,using the following code:

```
private AppDomain CreateAppDomain(string applicationName)
    {
        var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var fi = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var info = new AppDomainSetup
        {
            ConfigurationFile = @"D:\Deploy\App\web.config",
            ApplicationBase = @"D:\Deploy\App",
            ApplicationName = applicationName,
            CachePath = fi.Directory.Parent.FullName + @"\Temp",
            ShadowCopyDirectories = @"D:\Deploy\App\bin",
            PrivateBinPath = "bin",
            ShadowCopyFiles = "true"
        };

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(uid.ToString(), null, info);
        return domain;
    }
```

How we're able to test out this theory is by calling AppDomain.Unload(domain) against that created domain, and while we get an DomainUnloadException, this does prevent the job from freezing after being run twice.

We still haven't determined exactly what's within the domain that's getting locked up and preventing us to run the job more than twice, and guidance to learn more about that will be helpful. In the meantime, we're using this workaround of unloading the app domain for now.